# How to set up VSCode, Python interpreters?

Tags: software-installation, python3, 20.10, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Linux, coming from Windows 10 and had VSCode set up on it. Now VSCode asks me to select a Python interpreter, but I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu, so why does it show me two identical python3 interpreters but on different locations?

[image: check the screenshot first]

I did install only pip and ipython (`sudo apt install python3-pip && sudo pip install ipython`), so it should not show two of them.

How does the selecting one of them affect me, for example I run `sudo pip install mysql-connector`. Which one (`/usr/bin` or `/bin`) will have it? Are they same? How do I get rid of one of them, or is it just normal and it wouldn't affect anything if I select either one out of them?

Comment: One question per question.

Comment: @David roger that